# Laravel reduce number of queries to retrieve data from several columns with different conditions

Tags: laravel, database, eloquent

Suppose a user is looking for data via input form by entering a Customer ID. Then, a page will appear containing data related to food, drink, and appetizer.

This is snippet from Model file

```
public  function scopeSearch($query)
{
        return $query->Where([
            ['Customer ID', request('customer_id')], 
        ]);
}

public function scopeFood($query)
{
        return $query->Where('Food Column', 'LIKE', 'Fried'. "%");
}

public function scopeDrink($query)
{
        return $query->Where('Drink Column', 'LIKE', 'Juice'. "%");
}

public function scopeAppetizer($query)
{
        return $query->Where('Appetizer Column', 'LIKE', 'Hummus'. "%");
}
```

and this is snippet from Controller file.

```
public function show(){
        return view('menu', [
            'fried_food' => Table::search()->orderBy('Date', 'DESC')->food()->get(), 
            'juice_drink' => Table::search()->orderBy('Date', 'DESC')->drink()->get(),
            'hummus_appetizer' => Table::search()->orderBy('Date', 'DESC')->appetizer()->get(),
        ]);
    }
```

The problem is that Laravel do 3 queries. In the future I will apply more scopes, and of course it will take longer. How to make it more efficient?

Comment: How about get all the data using `orWhere()` then you can just divide them using the collection helper so that you only need to query one time.

Comment: Do you know any SQL query that fetches these kind of data with one query? I think the notion of problem forces us to run 3 queries and it is not a problem related to Laravel.

Comment: @xenooooo Is it without scope? If so, it will make it less well written

Answer (score 0):

As I understood you, when someone enters `customer_id` you want to retrieve data related to that customer?

Why don't you make a model for customers and then just eager load the data?

Should look something like this:

```
Customer::select(['columns', 'you','want'])->with(['relations','you','want'])->get() // three different relations

or (if foods are related to each other too)

Customer::select(['columns', 'you','want'])->with('relations.you.want')->get() // three nested relations
```

Comment: I use one table. The scope is for retrieving data for some column in one table. Is eager load can applied to one table?

Comment: @HerzaRyo I mean, you want to eager load other tables. For example, you want to pull posts WITH comments. This WITH is your eager load. So it would look like ```Post::with('comments')```. If you want to pull certain data from one table, then use this `select` as I have used in the code snippet. But, as I see you want something like filters. You could put some kind of checkboxes where users can check what they want (food, drinks, etc) and then check in the URL what you have of the params. You are going to check it with `$request->has()`  and you want then to use `->when($request->has('food'))`.